# Minimum of a non-convex function

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Let,
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y^2}+\left(\frac{x}{y}+\sqrt{2-\frac{1-x^2}{y^2}}\right)^2,
\end{align}

where $0 \le x\le 1$, $-1 \le y \le0$, $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ and $x^2 + 2y^2 \ge 1$. What is the $\min\limits_{x,y}f(x,y)$ subject to these constraints?

---

$f(x,y)$ is not convex under these constraints because $0 \le x\le 1$, $-1 \le y \le0$, $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ and $x^2 + 2y^2 \ge 1$ is not a convex set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given,
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y^2}+\left(\frac{x}{y}+\sqrt{2-\frac{1-x^2}{y^2}}\right)^2,
\end{align}

where $0 \le x\le 1$, $-1 \le y \le0$, $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ and $x^2 + 2y^2 \ge 1$.

We can find the $\min\limits_{x,y}f(x,y)$ when $\nabla f(x,y)=0$

Thus, we can expand $f(x,y)$ to become:

$$f(x,y) = 2 + \frac{2 x^2}{y^2} + \frac{2 x}{y}\sqrt{2 - \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{x^2}{y^2}}$$

Then, the gradient becomes:

$$\nabla f(x,y) = \left( \frac{4xy\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}+4x^2+4y^2-2}{y^3\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}},
\frac{4x^2y\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}+4x^3+4xy^2-4x}{y^4\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}}\right)$$

The minimum of the function will happen when $\nabla f(x,y) = 0$, thus we must solve for such a situation:

The first part:

$$\frac{4xy\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}+4x^2+4y^2-2}{y^3\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}}=0,$$
$$2xy\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}+2x^2+2y^2-1=0,$$
$$2x^2y\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}+2x^3+2xy^2-x=0$$

---

The second part:

$$\frac{4x^2y\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}+4x^3+4xy^2-4x}{y^4\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}} = 0,$$

$$x^2y\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}+x^3+xy^2-x = 0,$$
$$x^2y\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2y^2-1}{y^2}}=-x^3-xy^2+x$$

---

We can substitute the second part into the first part like so:

$$2(-x^3-xy^2+x)+2x^3+2xy^2-x=0$$
$$x=0$$

Thus, the minimum will occur when $x=0$. Thus, we plug in $x=0$ to the original function like so:

$$f(y)=\frac{1}{y^2}+2-\frac{1}{y^2}$$

where $x=0$, $-1 \le y \le0$, $y^2 \le 1$ and $2y^2 \ge 1$.

Which then reduces to:

$$f(y)=2$$

where $x=0$, $-1 \le y \le0$, $y^2 \le 1$ and $2y^2 \ge 1$.

However, the constraint $y^2 \le 1$ is equivalent to $-1\le y \le 1$, but is dominated by $-1 \le y \le 0$, and $2y^2 \ge 1$ is equivalent to $y^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}$ which is equivalent to $y \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $y \le -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Thus, the minimum will occur when $x=0$, and for any value of $y$ that satisfies $-1\le y \le -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks, let me check everything!

Comment: Thanks, so the idea is to forget about the constraints and calculate the minimum of $f(x,y)$ and then see if $\argmin f(x,y)$ falls in the region determined by the constraints which is the case here. Right?

Comment: Correct! As it's easier to find a part of the local solution (since it's non-convex) and then try to find nearby points that fit the other points that local solution

Comment: Could you please be more clear? I do not follow what you try to say here!

Comment: Ah sorry, for non-linear optimization problems, we are looking for a solution that satisfies when the gradient of the objective function is zero. So what we do is we try to solved the objective function for that property and we'll get something where one variable is equal to some other values/variables (in other words, we solved the problem for one variable). Then, we must take that partial solution and solve for the rest of the optimization model for the other variables. For example, with the given problem we solved the gradient for $x=0$, and then we were left with trying to solve for $y$

Comment: but yes we do forget about the constraints temporarily, and then try to solve for them after the substitution is made. Sometimes, we are fortunate enough to get exact solutions for the other variables, but in this case we found a region

Comment: Thanks, that make sense!

Answer (score 1):

I'd plot this in Desmos, see below:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d8fof2su7r

as you can see, the minimum lies tangent to the curve $x^2+y^2=1$. To find this point exactly, try to compute for which $x$ and $y$ these curves have equal gradient. Or substitute $x^2 = 1-y^2$ into $f$. This would give you a function with one variable, which you should be able to investigate in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I am interested when $a=1$. In this the above analysis is not valid anymore! Am I right here?